# Hibernate/JPA mapping a map <entity, basic> using annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I am newish to Hibernate and I don't know if I am taking the right approach on this, I have tried googling this problem but it I only succeeded in getting < basic, entity> and xml based mapping.

Here is my table setup:
[image]

I am trying to have a map collection in the parent entity(table1) which has an entity key and a basic string value `Map<Table2, String> table2Propertymapping` where the `String` value is the value of the enum property field from the connecting table `table2_has_table1`, and the key is the respective table2 entity that owns the `table2_idtable2` foreighn key in the connecting table.

I have tried this annotation in `table1` entity

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "table2_idtable2")
@Column(name = "property")
@CollectionTable(name = "table2_has_table1", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "table1_idtable1", nullable = false, updatable = false))
Map<Table2, String> table2Propertymapping;
```

This succeeds in populating the map **but it deletes some values from the connecting table** during fetching.

**Note:** In my real database, the foreign keys in the connecting table have the same names as the parent primary keys, so for example `table2_idtable2` is called `idtable2` I don't know what effect this may have on the mapping.

So what is the correct way of getting entities using the connecting table and mapping them with that property in the connecting table? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, the problem was in the declaration of the relationships between the tables in my original database, which allowed null values in the joining table. The above mapping works after ensuring all foreign keys are same as the diagram above (which was generated by mysql workbench)